# Binding TextBlock foreground to Global.cs variable in xaml

Tags: xaml, binding, silverlight-5.0

I've been trawling the web trying to find a similar problem but can't find anything that solves my problem.

I have a static class holding global variables, some of these are colour variables which I want to be able to bind in my xaml controls such that I only have to change one variable to change the lot (the reason for global variables).

The class namespace is `MyApp.Assets.Resources` the class name is `Global`(.cs).
In my class I have variables named `DEFAULTCOLOR`, `OKCOLOR` and `ALARMCOLOR`.

My xaml:

```
<UserControl
    <!-- ... -->
    xmlns:custom="clr-namespace:InspectionDB.Assets.Resources"
>
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <custom:Global x:Name="global"/> <!-- THIS GIVES AN ERROR SEE BELOW-->

        <common:HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="Level1" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource localTreeImgConverter}}"/>
                <TextBlock {Binding...} />
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding Type, Converter={StaticResource localStatusVisibilityConverter}}">
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0, 0,0" Text="[ " Foreground="{Binding DEFAULTCOLOR, Source={StaticResource global}}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Critical}" Foreground="{Binding ALARMCOLOR, Source={StaticResource global}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" | " Foreground="{Binding DEFAULTCOLOR, Source={StaticResource global}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding OK}" Foreground="{Binding OKCOLOR, Source={StaticResource global}}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text=" ]" Foreground="{Binding DEFAULTCOLOR, Source={StaticResource global}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </common:HierarchicalDataTemplate>

    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <!-- Where the hierarchical template is used --> 
    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

The part in the Resources throws an error as well as the binding:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'ApplicationProxy' to type 'Microsoft.Expression.DesignModel.DocumentModel.DocumentNode'.
```

What is wrong with my code and how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what my problem was, and therefore why I couldn't find any similar situation.

I had `public class Global : App` - don't ask me why, I'm sure there was a valid reason long ago but it meant it had some kind of funky circular referencing going on.

Problem solved.